# Want to update data.js with some function (No Database)

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a data file, named **data.js** which is like this :

For working in fiddle, I have used this data in the main code only, but otherwise it is form of **data.js**

```
var data = [{
      year: "first",
      redDelicious: "10",
      mcintosh: "0",
      oranges: "19"
    }, {
      year: "second",
      redDelicious: "12",
      mcintosh: "0",
      oranges: "15"
    }, {
      year: "third",
      redDelicious: "05",
      mcintosh: "0",
      oranges: "28"
    }, {
      year: "fourth",
      redDelicious: "14",
      mcintosh: "0",
      oranges: "12"
    },

  ];
```

As we can see, **mcintosh** is zero in all the cases, this is how, it is initialized. I want to update this **mcintosh**, every time I run a function which will generate the value to be updated into **mcintosh**.
I am using this to make stacked bar chart where value **mcintosh** will be stacked on **redDelicious** on it.
Working [fiddle for above work is here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/hawkeye15/wLs6p6wr/) where you will get the stacked bar chart.

Comment: So you want to edit a file with js?

Comment: Yup. That will make code look good otherwise there will be lots of data in the script itself.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with client side js. Maybe with localStorage or nodejs (server-side). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087881/how-to-save-and-edit-a-file-using-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339679/edit-a-file-using-javascript

Comment: @echonax Is it possible to update it,  if the data is there in the same js file, like I have used the data in my fiddle. Not a separate js file but in the same js file.

Comment: Can you please guide me or help me to do that, may be by making changes into fiddle. I am not much into javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here's the result : [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/wLs6p6wr/1/)

I've wrapped your function with `update()` so we can call it again.

I've added a button so we can increment the mcintosh key in your data.
Then on button click I removed the `<g>` elements under the svg, incremented your second mcintosh value and called update to redraw the updated data.

I've used jquery to bind the click event but you can change it to d3 if you want.

Comment: That's great, I checked it by updating other elements also like data[2].mcintosh. Its working fine. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Hope I can update with some variable also which will be passed inside the function through some parameter, as I can't fix it, what number to be updated.