# How do I let user save a file and keep editing that file in browser Javascript only?

Tags: javascript, file, browser, filesystems, edit

I believe it would not be possible due to security reason as stated in [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469243/edit-file-pure-js) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339679/edit-a-file-using-javascript) [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672518/modify-a-local-file-with-javascript) on StackOverflow. However, when I use the Diagram app at https://app.diagrams.net/ I realized they could ask me to save a file, and somehow keep that file reference and whenever I click Save on the app, my local file on hard drive changes **(no new download)**.

I know it's only possible to upload/download a file and believe you cannot edit it (using Blob with FileReader etc). How do they achieve that? The app is open source but unfortunately plowing through the [source code of their File Handler](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/blob/0a442de57fe4c21ca9f6fa945279130e9d31ac24/src/main/webapp/js/diagramly/LocalFile.js#L11) I still cannot find out what API they are using. I don't remember installing any plugin or app in my browser.

I also notice there is this permission in my browser so I guess it's some standard API, but even using that as keyword, all leads back to StackOverflow articles saying it's not possible.

[image]

Is it a new API I am not aware of? What am I looking for?

Comment: Do you mean FileSaver.js? localStorage is another way you could try to do it

Comment: Nope, `localStorage` does not create a physical file or let user choose where it is. They create real file on hard drive (i.e `test.drawio` is a XML text file)

Comment: About FileSaver.js I am not sure but a quick look at their API, look like their only function is to create and download a file, not edit them? I may be wrong though.

Comment: Using FileSaver.js if you have the file loaded and you make changes you can save those changes back to the file system with FileSaver.js (via a 'Save' dialog). Does this match the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: Not sure if it's the same thing but I tried some of their demo pages, all of them simply save using the browser's setting which I can achieve using standard Javascript. Also the permission didn't show up like screenshot above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` to achieve this without needing any other permission from the user.

`localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));`

If your data is just JSON then this would work, however if you have custom data types, you can take a look [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/).

Edit:

Since you wanted to save the file directly to the device and edit it, you can take a look at File System Access API. This article [here](https://web.dev/file-system-access/) explains it.

You can load the file first by using,

```
let fileHandle;
butOpenFile.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker();
  const file = await fileHandle.getFile();
  const contents = await file.text();
  textArea.value = contents;
});
```

Once you have the file handle you should be able to write to the file without requesting to download a new file everytime there is a change.

```
async function writeFile(fileHandle, contents) {
  // Create a FileSystemWritableFileStream to write to.
  const writable = await fileHandle.createWritable();
  // Write the contents of the file to the stream.
  await writable.write(contents);
  // Close the file and write the contents to disk.
  await writable.close();
}
```

The codes are from the article I have linked above and the article explains everything much clearly. It's worth reading.

Comment: Nope, `localStorage` does not create a physical file or let user choose where it is. They create real file on hard drive (i.e test.drawio is a XML text file). Also `localStorage` has a limit of 5MB as well on most browsers as well.

Comment: Have you looked at the File System Access API?

Comment: Ah yes, it's the FileSystem API. Can confirm it has the same behavior. Now I notice it does not work in Firefox. For the app when running on Firefox they fall back to the default browser behavior (i.e new download on save).